# Using CUPS interface to install printer on another network

Tags: printing, cups

I want to install a printer via the CUPS interface in Ubuntu. My IP is of the sort aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd and the printer's IP is of the sort aaa.bbb.eee.fff. This printer is visible to Windows PCs in my network but not to my Ubuntu machine, and CUPS does not detect it. I am guessing this is happening because printer and PC are not within the same IP domain.

Checking the printer's info, it has most protocols enabled, including TCP/IP, IPP, SNMP, mDNS, etc.

Any ideas on to to get it to work?

In case it helps, it's a Konica Minolta Bizhub 20P.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is involves more than just your printer; you have to set a virtual network interface with the printer's IP class. Let's say your Linux has a `192.168.0.x` address while the printer has a `192.168.1.x` address

```
sudo ifconfig
```

shows you all your network interfaces, if you have just one, it's `eth0` (the second one `eth1`, etc); add this to `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0  inet static
    address 192.168.1.y
```

No need to set gateway, as your network traffic defaults to the `eth0` IP

Comment: This is not working for me. My only network interface is eth2 rather than eth0 (obviously I'm using eth2:0 in the interfaces files using your configuration example), but I don't think that's related.